# Conditional Formatting Rule: Highlight Row when Cell Value in X Column Begins With

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to highlight rows in my spreadsheet where cell values in Column B start with qr.

I tried following ExcelJet's example "Highlight cells that begin with," but this method will ONLY highlight cells. It will also highlight other cells in other columns where cell's value (string) begins with qr.

I did come up with a small googled solution.

Created a rule within Conditional Formatting and used this.

=SEARCH("qr",CONCATENATE($A2, $B2, $C2, $D2,$E2,$F2,$G2))=1

The problem with this solution is it will concatenate the rows in which qr exists and highlight them. It will also do this to rows in which a cell's value other than in column B starts with qr.

May I get some help with this please?

---

I wasn't able to produce a solution table for my question, but the solution would be the same table with ROW 2 AND ROW 5 highlighted only. The current rule I'm applying will highlight ROW 2,3, and 5 and concatenate their cells.

```
 |---|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
 |   |          A          |         B        |         C           |    
 |---|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
 | 1 |      Full Name      |     Username     |    Email Address    |
 |---|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
 | 2 |        Mario        |    qrmrincon     | mrodrigez@yahoo.com | 
 |---|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
 | 3 |        Sofia        |    sgrahama3     |  recio1@hotmail.com |         
 |---|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
 | 4 |        Qrig         |     grecio1      |   recio1@msn.com    |   
 |---|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
 | 5 |        Mora         |    qrmturner2    |   turner2@aol.com   |   
 |---|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Comment: `LEFT($B2, 2) = "qr"`

Comment: FYI, that formula you have is basically looking for `qr` in this string: `Marioqrmrinconmrodrigez@yahoo.com...` where the ellipses are also the text in columns D:G.  I'm 99% sure you don't want this, because if someone's name is `Maliq` and their username begins `rXYZ`, then it'll think it found a match for `qr`.

Answer (score 0):

For the Conditional Formatting formula, just use:

```
=LEFT($B2,2)="qr"
```

Then for the "Applies to" range, put:

```
=$A$2:$C$100
```

(Adjust that last row based on the data)

And just format as you wish (a `Fill` is likely what you want).

Comment: beat me by 20 seconds ;)